# Resize container div after ajax request

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a webpage where I am loading a twitter feed via ajax. My html and jquery call look like this:

```
<body>
<div class="document-wrapper">
    <div class="document">
        <div class="content">   
                <div class="right-column">
                    <h2 class="twitter-header">Recent Tweets</h2>
                    <div class="twitter-feed" id="feed">
                    </div>
                </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#feed').load("/Home/Twitter", '', showNewContent)
   }); 
   function showNewContent() {  

    }  
</script>
</div>(document)
<div class="document-end"></div>
```

It loads the result properly into the feed div, but none of the containers resize their height and it overflows poorly. All of the divs have `height:auto;` set on them, but that appears to do nothing. If I set a min-height on the document class, it sort of works, but I do not want to have that in there statically.

After closer inspection, it appears that the document div is resizing, but it is not pushing eveything below it down when it resizes. The page footer stays in place, and the new content is rendered behind it, and is not selectable or anything.

Is there a way to get the page to resize everything properly after the ajax call?

**Edit: Heres some css:**

```
.footer-wrapper,
.document-wrapper {
width       : 960px;
margin      : 0 auto;
position    : relative;
height      : auto;
}

.document-wrapper { background : url(background-content.jpg) top repeat-y; }

.document { 
padding : 0 35px 75px 35px;
height: auto;
}

.document-end {
height      : 39px;
width       : 960px;
margin      : 0;
background  : url(background-content-end.jpg) top no-repeat;
}

.right-column {
float       : right;
width       : 300px;
font-size   : 90%;
position    : relative;
left        : -30px;
padding     : 4px 0 0 0;
height: auto;
}

.twitter-feed 
{
height:auto;
color       : #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Will you post your associated css?

Comment: Are any of the parents using `display:inline`?

Comment: no inline. The css is pretty big, and I'm not sure what is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your elements don't exactly have "layout". When going for a fluid feel you shouldn't have to explicitly set dimensions. Divs should auto adjust.

Whenever I have divs that won't take on children dimensions properly I add clear: both; and float: left:

```
.yourDiv {
   clear: both;
   float: left;/* or right */
}
```

That almost always works for me.

Otherwise, you will have to calculate the combined heights of the children and set the container to that height.

Comment: It looks like if I add clear:both; to enough elements, it works. I definitely don't want float:left, though. That screws all kinds of things up. I've never used clear before. What is it?

Comment: float: left on a div makes it so other divs with float: left will be on the same line as eachother as long as there is enough space. Also, for some reason, float: left forces the div to be fluid. So, we use clear: both so that it "clears" both sides. You can do clear: left and clear: right too. Clear: both means nothing will sit on the left or right side.